# Ethernet gives me 169.254.xx.xx

Tags: networking, ethernet

When I try to connect my computer to the internet via Ethernet I get 'unidentified network', my IP address becomes 169.254.xx.xx and has no default gateway.
Setting a static IP address still gives me the 'unidentified network'.
I've checked the DHCP settings on my router and they are all fine.
I've tried replacing my ethernet cables too as a few sources says it may be a faulty wire.

edit:
forgot to actually ask a question. Does anyone know a possible way to fix this issue?
Also I've already tried the suggested fixes listed here:
[I am using Windows 7 and I get a 169.254.x.x ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/840388/i-am-using-windows-7-and-i-get-a-169-254-x-x-ip-address) to no avail. WiFi works just fine so it's not that. I've tried replacing the cables and nothing. I am using a powerline adapter so it might be those.

Comment: You never asked a Question?, It means it cannot reach the router to get an ip address using dhcp.

Comment: If this problem is not limited to Ethernet, its DHCP service in your computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am using Windows 7 and I get a 169.254.x.x ip address](http://superuser.com/questions/840388/i-am-using-windows-7-and-i-get-a-169-254-x-x-ip-address)

Comment: Already tried all of the suggested fixes in that article.

Comment: Can you describe your setup? What is connected to what? Have you confirmed that the two powerline adapters see each other?

Answer (score 0):

Your DHCP service is not working correctly... "getting" a 169.254.x.x address means your computer is not receiving a DHCP offer that it can accept. After an attempt to get DHCP, if an offer is not received or cannot be accepted for some reason, the adapter/network driver automatically assigns the interface a bogus IP address of 169.254.x.x

Comment: Which is why I tried assigning a static IP address.

Comment: And is that didn't work, you have a connectivity, hardware, or driver issue.

Comment: That much is obvious. I'm trying to find out where the problem lies. Do you have any idea what I could do to try fixing it?

Comment: So it is basic troubleshooting from this point, try another device, cable, look for link light, Wireshark trace, etc... You have to give us something to go on to help you, this could be any of 10 or so things and their is no magic answer. My first thing would be get a known good cable and a known good computer and try it, if it works, plug the same cable into to your device and retest

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after trying a few things I managed to get it working. The issue wasn't the cables or the computer itself it was simply the powerline adapters. For some reason they were out of sync and thus no data was being transferred between them. Thank you all for the help.