# strange ip address raspbian and I can no longer ssh

Tags: networking, router, ssh, ip, raspberry-pi

In the past I have been able to ssh into the pi easily but a couple of days ago I could no longer find the pi ip address in the router page. I made a fresh install of raspbian and plugged it into a ethernet cable and it tells me that the ip is `169.254.211.205`, which I find very strange. I would usually expect an ip address something like: `192.168.20.x`, but I don't know why the pi is giving me this ip address or how to go back to the old one. Does anybody know what this problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=169.254

Comment: You didn't respond to anyone with the last question you had...

Comment: it's a 0-conf address, you have to set your IP by hand: connect your PI to the TV and edit the /etc/host file properly

Comment: Have you verified if your [DHCP service](https://superuser.com/questions/840388/i-am-using-windows-7-and-i-get-a-169-254-x-x-ip-address) is running?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a hiccup fixed by rebooting the router; no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. All I had to do was give my router a reboot and it worked. (-: