# Router with no IPv4 address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ipv6

I have a router that does not have an IPv4 address as seen in the photo

[Network output from my computer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps7yz.png)

Is there a way to connect to it and fix that? I tried connecting using the IPv6 name http://[fe80::ee08:6bff:fedd:63d] but id did not work.

It has openWRT on it if that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: No, that image describes a host that configured itself with a link-local (APIPA) address. It did not get that address from any type of DHCP. That network block (`169.254.0.0/16`) is not allowed to be routed, and addresses in that block are not allowed to be statically or manually assigned, nor is that range allowed to be subnetted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am using Windows 7 and I get a 169.254.x.x ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/840388/i-am-using-windows-7-and-i-get-a-169-254-x-x-ip-address)

Comment: Also, your IPv6 address is a link-local address, which is not allowed to be routed, and you did not include the required Zone ID. Every IPv6 interface uses the same network, so you must use a Zone ID to distinguish the specific network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a DHCP assigned address from the OpenWrt device.

Try setting a static IP on your wifi connection, the default LAN ip range of a OpenWrt device is 192.168.1.1/24 so you need to set your wifi to:

```
ip: 192.168.1.10
netmask: 192.168.255.0
gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Either you can now login at http://192.168.1.1 (default username is root without password for a fresh installed OpenWrt). Perhaps you need to enable the DHCP server on the LAN network.

If that does not work, try to ping from a MacOS terminal:

```
$ping 192.168.1.1
```

If you do not get a ping reply, there is something else wrong with the actual network.

Answer (score 0):

It's well known that browsers refuse to accept IPv6 link-local address literals as the host part of a URL. So you need a different address for the router.

Fortunately it appears your network is also configured with an IPv6 unique local address network, `fd4f:3537:6693::/48`, where your LAN is on `fd4f:3537:6693::/64`.

This means the router *should* be avaiable on the subnet router anycast address, which is the zero address of the subnet, i.e. `fd4f:3537:6693::`.

But not all routers listen to this address, so there is another way to find its other IPv6 addresses, and that is by pinging the all routers multicast address, `ff02::2`. Open a Terminal.app and run:

```
ping6 ff02::2%wlan0
```

(where `wlan0` is the interface name of your Wi-Fi interface)

If your router responds to pings, this should return responses from at least two addresses, one of which is in the ULA prefix, and which you can then use in a URL.

Either way, once you have an address, try accessing it in your browser:

```
http://[fd4f:3537:6693::<whatever>]/
```

Even this isn't guaranteed to work, because your router might not be serving its built in web server on IPv6. But it's what I would do to try to get back in.