# windows says wifi has no valid IP address but ipconfig says it does?

Tags: networking

Windows troubleshooter

[image: windows troubleshooter]

`ipconfig /all`

[image: ipconfig /all]

Comment: 169.254.x.x is not a "valid" IP Address, it's a self-assigned & essentially non-routable address known as a [Link-Local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) that signifies it couldn't find a DHCP server. Default Gateway is also empty, confirming that. Your IPv6 address is also link local [though I'm not very good with v6, fe80 is equivalent to 169.254]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am using Windows 7 and I get a 169.254.x.x ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/840388/i-am-using-windows-7-and-i-get-a-169-254-x-x-ip-address)

Comment: To what device are you connecting via your WiFi? Is it your home router? What are you trying to do? Access the internet? Do you get a connection if you connect other devices via WLAN or via (wired) Ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Any IP configuration in ipconfig that starts with 169 means that it is not configured properly. Even though it "has an IP address" it's stating that it's not a valid one. More info is about this is [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-a-169-IP-address-so-you-can-get-online)

This happens when your computer is not getting a IP or proper IP from your router. In this case it may be either your computer or your router.

I would try going to control panel, network and internet, network and sharing center, change adapter settings. Then right click on your wifi network adapter and click properties. Double click internet protocol version 4 and set everything as automatic if it hasn't been already. If that does not solve the problem I would reconnect the wifi network and restart. If none of that works you may need to do a network reset. Search "network reset" in the search bar and do a full reset. You will need to provide the wifi password again when the reset and restart is done so make sure you have your passwords.

The problem may also be in your router as it may not be providing an IP address for your computer. Restart the router (Unplug for a minute and plug back in) and do a full reset of the router (hold the reset button) if restarting doesn't work.